# WPF: simple TextBox data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox

I have this class:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public String Name2;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Name2 = new String('a', 5);
        myGrid.DataContext = this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And I want to display the string `Name2` in the textbox.

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" Height="437.274">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2}"/>
</Grid>
```

But the string isn't displayed. Also, if the string `Name2` is updated periodically using a `TimerCallback`, do I need to do anything to make sure the textbox is updated when the data changes?

Comment: As a tip, you can format code by indenting by four spaces or using the 101010 button -- saves manually mucking around with br tags and escaping angle brackets!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Name2 is a field.  WPF binds only to properties.  Change it to:

```
public string Name2 { get; set; }
```

Be warned that with this minimal implementation, your TextBox won't respond to programmatic changes to Name2.  So for your timer update scenario, you'll need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  private string _name2;

  public string Name2
  {
    get { return _name2; }
    set
    {
      if (value != _name2)
      {
         _name2 = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Name2");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should consider moving this to a separate data object rather than on your Window class.

Comment: Example from MSDN on implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (scroll down to DemoCustomer implementation): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Following your example I do 
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name2}"></Label>
But it does not work

Answer (score 10):

Just for future needs.

In Visual Studio 2013 with .NET Framework 4.5, for a window property, try adding `ElementName=window` to make it work.

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" Height="437.274">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2, ElementName=window}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: On XAML side, <TextBox Text="Binding Name2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/> once Name2 has been included in the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 9):

Your Window is not implementing the necessary data binding notifications that the grid requires to use it as a data source, namely the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

Your "Name2" string needs also to be a property and not a public variable, as data binding is for use with properties.

Implementing the necessary interfaces for using an object as a data source can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).