# SImple WPF Example that describes DATA Binding and Validation

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am New to WPF.
I want Simple WPF Application Example, that have some textboxes and validation(numeric range,Email) on it
If all the Validation are true then ok button will be enable otherwise disable
Detail Example will be Appreciated
Thank You

Comment: Don't be so lazy. Do some research yourself: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=WPF%20data%20binding%20validation%20example

Comment: @Daniel thank you for ruining my reputaion, Sir, i already tried hard, i had shown more than 10 examples but neither one discribe all the simple things i want, and some example was really complicated for fresher, so please can you under stand that problem and take right step rather than demotivation me

Comment: @Daniel Sir, in my question i already told that I am new to WPF, so that means i want simple example, from where i can start learing, not confuson with all other functionalities

Comment: Really, there are all kinds of example all over the internet. If you can't find the rights one for you or this doesn't fit your learning style, you should consider buying a book for a good introduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [WPF: simple TextBox data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725554/wpf-simple-textbox-data-binding) Do google before posting questions.There are lots of examples and tutorials out there

also 
[WPF Basic Data Binding FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx)

Comment: Thank You for your reply, Sir,I have alredy tried, but i couldn't get simple example that can lead me to next step, I m new to WPF,fresher always want simple explanation, other example confues me a lot with other functionalities,so I hope U will understand my problem, I am not asking for how to bind, i had asked that i want simple application example that describes binding with validation and if validation passes then n then only button will be enabled, if u have any llink that provides complete solution than please post on comment, Thank you very much

Comment: if that is the thing to enable or disable buttom based on input then simple is that in the Text change event of textbox validate that input and on that decision make button enable or disable