# Databinding in WPF - textboxes to a business object added via Data / Add New Data Source

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio, data-binding, textbox

Very simple in WinForms, but in WPF - using `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`es, I can't figure out how I could bind them to a business object, which I just added as data source (`Data`, `Add New Data Source`, `Object`...); in the designer, that is.

Working with WinForms, all I have to do is to go to its `Properties`, then `DataBindings` and `Advanced`, where I can just bind its property with a property of the object.

What is the equivalent of doing that in WPF?

Comment: WPF: simple TextBox data binding - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1725554/485076

Answer (score 1):

Very easy in XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YourProperty}" />
```

In VS2010 designer you can also do it from the property grid