# How to setup simple data binding in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have come back to this question to flag it as a duplicate as its essence was how to set up a basic data binding, which has been answered many times, here is one of the good answers: (I would delete this question if I could)

[WPF: simple TextBox data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725554/wpf-simple-textbox-data-binding)

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to read a book or an article about the essentials of a technology *before* trying to use it. For WPF data binding I'd suggest to read the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN for a basic understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to bind to a Method instead of a property.
Try something like this:

```
public static bool fruitLimits
{
    get
    { /*your method code here*/ }
}
```

EDIT:
There is no way to pass arguments into the Property, so if you don't have access to the values of the text box you may have to write a converter that gets these values passed. Here the basics: [link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)
You can pass one object as the value and the other as the parameter.
The converter then processes the information and returns a bool.
Here an example of what the Binding of this Converter should look like:

Here an example, your binding should look something like this:

```
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converterKey}">
                            <Binding ElementName="boxVariable" />
                            <Binding ElementName="textboxDec" Path="Text" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
```

Replace the "ElementName=boxVariable" and "ElementName=textboxDec" with the names of the controls you want to pass. You may have to add "Path=Text" on the textbox binding.

Then in the IMultiValueConverter do something like this:

```
public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value[0].GetType().Equals(typeof(ComboBox)) && value[1].GetType().Equals(typeof(String)))
    { 
        ComboBox boxVariable = value[0] as ComboBox;
        string textboxDec = value[1] as String;

        /* your method code here, returns Boolean */
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a converter ? - will it use the result from my method fruitLimits? and then how would it be passed to the property

Comment: Hi R.jauch thanks for the continuing help, for the DataTrigger it says, A'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterParameter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependecyProperty of a DependencyObject

Comment: Updated my answer to use a MultiValueConverter, now you should be able to bind to both controls