# binding error in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

i have created an instance of a class in the code and bind one of the properties of that class named"Name" to a textbox but the binding does not work.
can you help me?
code behind:

```
    public partial class BlackOilWindow : FluidsWindowClass
    {
        public Classes.ModelInOutClasses.BlackOilFluidModel _FluidBlackOilClass;
        public BlackOilWindow(Classes.ModelInOutClasses.BlackOilFluidModel inputBlackOilClass):base(inputBlackOilClass)
        {
            if (inputBlackOilClass == null)
            {
                inputBlackOilClass = new ModelInOutClasses.BlackOilFluidModel();
            }
            _FluidBlackOilClass = inputBlackOilClass;
            InitializeComponent();



        }
   }
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBox 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="23" 
    Margin="73,7,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120" 
    Text="{Binding ElementName=_FluidBlackOilClass, Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />
```

Comment: _FluidBlackOilClass has to be a property, not a member

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: simple TextBox data binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725554/wpf-simple-textbox-data-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems. First, it has to be a property (and take that underscore off the front if it's public; by convention, the underscore prefix means "private field"):

```
public Classes.ModelInOutClasses.BlackOilFluidModel FluidBlackOilClass {
    get; set;
}
```

Second, by default, the `Binding` looks for the specified property on the `DataContext` object. As far as I can tell from what you're saying, the `Window`'s `DataContext` is `null`. `ElementName` is used to refer to a *control*, a UI control, that has an `x:Name` property. `FluidBlackOilClass` is not that. And (trivia time!) `Mode` is unneeded in this case; the control's property has a default value for that, and `TwoWay` is the default for `TextBox.Text`.

So your binding can't work anyway, regardless of whether `FluidBlackOilClass` is a field or property. `FluidBlackOilClass` is a property of the window. Here's how to bind to a property of the window (or in this case, a property that belongs to a property of the window -- same difference, different `Path`):

```
<TextBox 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="23" 
    Margin="73,7,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120" 
    Text="{Binding FluidBlackOilClass.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />
```

You'd be better off with a proper viewmodel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You should *not* implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Window` as suggested in [the accepted answer to this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1725628/424129). That seems arbitrary at first, but you soon find that the separation makes your code much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You used binding on a member of the class. Binding works only for Properties. A fast correction would be this:

```
 public Classes.ModelInOutClasses.BlackOilFluidModel _FluidBlackOilClass{get;set;}
```

Adapt the solution to your requirements.