# C# Wpf textbox difference between TextChanged and PreviewTextInput

Tags: wpf, events

I am currently implementing a validation for my textbox and I am not sure which Event to choose, `TextChanged` or `PreviewTextInput`, as there seems to be no difference.

How are those events different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from framework documentation:

**[UIElement.PreviewTextInput Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput?view=netframework-4.7.2)**

> The PreviewTextInput event allows a component or application to listen
>   for text input in a device-independent manner. The keyboard is the
>   primary means of PreviewTextInput; but speech, handwriting, and other
>   input devices can also generate PreviewTextInput.
>
> Because of key combinations—either in default keyboards or through
>   input method editors—multiple key events may raise just one text input
>   event.
>
> This event creates an alias for the
>   TextCompositionManager.PreviewTextInput attached event for this class,
>   so that PreviewTextInput is part of the class members list when
>   UIElement is inherited as a base element. Event handlers that are
>   attached to the PreviewTextInput event are attached to the underlying
>   TextCompositionManager.PreviewTextInput attached event and receive the
>   same event data instance.

**[TextBoxBase.TextChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)**

> For a TextBox, this event occurs when its text changes; for a
>   RichTextBox, this event occurs when any content or formatting changes
>   (for example, images, table, or background color).

**My 2 cents:**

There is a big difference between these two events. `TextChanged` event will be executed after textbox has processed text and updated control. On the other hand `PreviewTextInput` event will be executed when you have focus on the textbox and preform action on the input device(keyboard for example) before even textbox has any idea about upcoming input from the device.

Answer (score 0):

The [`PreviewTextInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput?view=netframework-4.7.2) event gets fired "when the `TextBox` gets text in a device-independent manner." The text property of the event argument of `PreviewTextInput` (which is of type [`TextCompositionEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs.textcomposition?view=netframework-4.7.2)) will only contain the text of the last input action. In the case of keyboard input, this will most likely be one key-down and thus only one character. Other input methods, such as voice input, could input more than one character at a time.

The [`TextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event looks at the `Text` property of a `TextBox` and occurs when its text changes in any way. Its event argument, of type `TextChangedEventArgs`, has a collection of `TextChange` objects that contain information about the changes that have been made.

As for which you should choose for validation, the answer is... *neither*. Since you wish to validate, I can only assume you will be using the entered text elsewhere in your project. In WPF, an [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish) (that's Model, View, ViewModel) architecture is preferred, which means we use [Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725554/wpf-simple-textbox-data-binding) for input. There are multiple ways of validating the text of a `TextBox` in MVVM, with my preferred methods being the [`IDataErrorInfo`](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1014426/Implementing-Validation-using-IDataErrorInfo-Inter) interface and [Binding Validation Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation). The former performs validation after the text data has been sent to the ViewModel, and the latter will validate the text before it's pushed to the ViewModel.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Important note: for binding rules to work the way the OP is looking for, you need to set "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" in the binding.