# Write To Output message (C# => TextBox)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, output

I have TextBox:

```
 <TextBox  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"               
           FontFamily="Consolas"
           Text="{Binding Path=Output}"
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
           AcceptsReturn="True"
           AcceptsTab="True" />
```

To inside this TextBox I want to send some/add the message:

```
public string Output { get; set; }
public void WriteToOutput(string message)
{
 Output += DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM HH:mm:ss") + " " + message + Environment.NewLine;
}     

public void LoadExcelFile()
{
  WriteToOutput("Start....")
  //SOME CODE
  WriteToOutput("End....")
}
```

Output should looks like:

```
Start...
End...
```

But the text it's not showing into TextBox. What is the reason?

Update: my MainViewModel.cs:

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class MainViewModel
{
....
}
```

I'm using `PropertyChanged.Fody`

Comment: OnPropertychanged. You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: You didn't implement INPC in your VM?

Comment: is the propertychanged event raised? (hahahha the triple simultaneous answers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: simple TextBox data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725554/wpf-simple-textbox-data-binding)

Comment: I have [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

A working example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string output;
    public string Output
    {
        get { return output; }
        set
        {
            output = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // notify the GUI that something has changed
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Output = "Hallo";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName: propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML code would look like this:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding Output}"/>`

As you can see, whenever the `Output` property changes, the `PropertyChanged` event will be called. Every GUI Element that is bound to that Property will know that something has changed.

Note: `[CallerMemberName]` automatically gets the name of the property the method has been called with. If you don't want to use it, remove it. You'd have to change the `OnPropertyChanged` call to `OnPropertyChanged("Output");`, though.

Comment: I have implemented [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]    public class MainViewModel

Comment: @4est have you added `OnPropertyChanged` to the setter?

Comment: Im using PropertyChanged.Fody and I think I don't need it?