# List in C# with a WPF Application advice for a beginner?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml

I am attempting to self-teach C# and have read a sizable number of textbooks and training programs which have been useful.  I'm now attempting to build my first application using C# and WPF/XAML. The application is intended to be a simple "Employee Records" app that stores some basic information from the UI into a list. However, I don't seem to be able to map the `TextBox`s in the UI to the code.

I have my `Label` and `TextBox` defined in `MainWindow.xaml` like this:

```
<Label x:Name="lbl_forename" Content="Forename" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" Height="26" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txt_forename" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="20,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Forename, Mode=TwoWay,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                    ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
                 Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=errorAwareTextBox}"/>
```

I have a class file `People.cs`:

```
public class People
{
   private string firstname; //field
   public string FirstName //property
   {
      get { return firstname; }
      set { firstname = value; }
   }
}
```

And I have tried building my list within the same class like this:

```
public static List<People> BuildList()
{
   //Store the list or collection of the data here
   return new List<People>
   {
      { new People() { firstname = Forename } }
   };
}
```

However, I'm getting:

> Error CS0103  The name 'Forename' does not exist in the current context

The same applies where I use `txt_Forename` and not `Forename`.

The same applies where I have the list in `public partial class MainWindow : Window`.

Comment: Your answer is probably available in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725554/wpf-simple-textbox-data-binding

Comment: if you want the text from the `TextBox` to be the first name, then use this:   `{ new People() { firstname = MainWidow.txt_forename.Text} }`. That also implies that the people class knows your view class or where ever that BuildList method is

Comment: You question is very confusing and unclear. Basically what you do is not correct. The error is coming from the firstname = Forename part. Forename is not known in that context. Perhaps if you could explain why you expected it to be there, maybe someone could help

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

The error comes from the fact that you are trying to access instance members from a `static` method.

---

Longer answer:

In WPF, when you give an XAML element a `Name`, it gets declared as an instance field of the class being created from that XAML file. A "field" being a named variable associated with a class, and "instance" meaning that each instance of that class has its own, separate variable by that name.

So, when you put `<TextBox x:Name="txt_forename"...` into your `MainWindow.xaml`. Your `MainWinow` class gets a field named `txt_forename`. Just as if you had added the code `TextBox txt_forename;` into the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file.

When the WPF application loads, it creates an instance of the "startup" window (e.g. `MainWindow`) and shows that instance of the window. But just like your `Person` class, there *can* potentially be more than one `MainWindow` instance and each one would have its own `txt_forename`.

Now let's take your method `public static List<People> BuildList()`. I'm going to assume for the moment that it's declared inside the `MainWindow` class.

The problem with this is that it's `static`. A `static` member of a class is shared by *all* instances of that class and so can't access fields/properties of any specific instance without being told which one. If you want to call `BuildList()` from inside an instance of `MainWindow` and have it look at the current value of `Forename`, you *don't* want a `static` method.

If `BuildList()` is declared *outside* of `MainWindow` (for some reason), or if you want it to remain `static` (again, for some reason), then you'd need to add a parameter to your method to tell it which instance of `MainWindow` you want to use. Something like:

```
public static List<People> BuildList(MainWindow window)
```